# Classification of biological samples with binary variables

Tags: classification, binary-data

**I have a question about a very basic classification problem.**

The objective is to discriminate between feature A and B. 
Where A is a specific biological sample, and B all others.
And the goal is to classify new unknown samples.

To do so I have 12 variables with binary data, representing the presence or absence of certain traits.

For example: 6 (3 known A and 3 known B) samples with 4 variables.

```
       Feature   Var1. Var2. Var3. Var4.  
Sample1    *A*       1     1     1     1  
Sample2    *A*       1     0     1     1  
Sample3    *A*       0     1     1     0  
Sample4    *B*       1     0     0     0  
Sample5    *B*       0     0     1     0  
sample6    *B*       0     1     1     0
```

What kind of classification algorithm can I use to predict a new unknown sample?

Comment: K nearest neighbor, naive Bayes, logistic regression, support vector machines, in roughly ascending order of complexity.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no theoretical model to suggest you possible relationships then stick to non-parametrics: start out with random forests, then if you start spotting some relationships try again with support vector machines.
Eventually, if some relationships appear clear, try out logistic regressions.

Parametrics will introduce specification errors, but they have clearer meanings and if well specified tend to be better.

After you have used a few algorithms, you'll have to choose the one that works best. Cross-Validation is the key tool there. Run the classification algorithms on 90% of the data and use them to predict the rest 10%. The algorithm that predicts better "wins".